# Get date out of sql server datetime

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to get the date from a SQL Server `datetime`, and then format the date. (i.e. `01-Jan-2000`) I'm using PHP.

currently, SQL is returning `2009-02-13 22:00:00.000`.

Comment: Make sure to take into account if the database uses UTC (or another TZ, I would highly recommend only UTC in the data) and how the data is to be presented. The actual date may be different depending on how it's interpreted -- note that there is no TZ offset present in the date (and there will be none from a datetime in sql :-)

Comment: @user569403: what PHP function are you using to parse this date?  `strtotime()` will parse this date correctly, even though it will drop the microsecond part.  If using `date()` directly on this string, that's not possible as `date()` requires an integer timestamp...  Odly enough, `date()` has a `u` format to return microseconds, even though `date()` is incapable of accepting or parsing `floats`.  Go figure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime($datetime_from_db));
```

Comment: @user569403: Where `$datetime_from_db` is the date column returned by your query.  For examples of what strings `strtotime()` can take, see the man page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.  For examples on reformatting dates using `date()` like in Dan Grossman's example, see http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: That is what i was doing before but some how it only prints 1-Jan-1970 , now i am using explode function and getting the date part out of that datetime.

Comment: If you're getting 1-Jan-1970 it most likely means that the value in $date_from_db is incorrect.  You should probably print it to the screen to verify whether or not it's what you expect if you're getting 1-Jan-1970

Comment: I think the fractional seconds isn't a supported format for parsing by `strtotime`, so he needs to take a substring of the date from the database.

Comment: you are correct - `strtotime()` returns an `int`, so even though it parses OP's date correctly, it does not return the microsecond.

Answer (score 1):

You can pool date in any format you want directly from mySQL query,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d-%b-%Y') FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `conncetionInfo => 'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>true`

`$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AdventureWorks", 'ReturnDatesAsStrings '=> true);`